# Deleting a post on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, post

I tried this approach but no luck, I keep getting an error.

> Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

```
Post::find($id)->delete();
```

Relationships:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that find::($id) didn't return anything (e.g. the id wasn't found), and hence there's no post object?

Comment: Well im sure it detects the post,

{{ Form::model($post, array('route' => array('post.delete', $post->id))) }}

Route::delete('post/delete/{id}', array('as'=>'post.delete', function($id)
{
    $post = post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    return Redirect::to('account')->with('message', 'You have deleted a space!');
}));

Comment: Wrong Form:: should be this but still not working. {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'post/delete/{id}', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'class' => 'data-abide')) }}

Comment: It deletes the post if I actually specify the id like ::find(1).

Comment: That seems to lead me to believe that either $id isn't what you think it is, or (maybe it doesn't matter) it's a string vs. a number and needs to be converted via intval() ?

Comment: Well it shows the right post id on the browser url. I tried the code below to link to the route but it doesn't seems to return to account page.

    <a href="post/delete/{{ $post->id }}" data-method="delete" class="small radius button">Delete Space</a>

    Route::delete('post/delete/{id}', function($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return View::make('account')->with('message', 'You have deleted a post!');
    });

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this.

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route'=>array('post.delete', $post->id))) }}
```

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way of like giving a message or confirmation whether to delete or cancel a post.

Comment: Yeah, do it easily with javascript.  On your submit, use `Form::submit('Submit', array('onclick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?")'));`